# Prove that the sequence k,k,k,...,k of length k+1 is graphic, thereby proving that there exist k-regular graphs on k+1 vertices

Tags: sequences-and-series, graph-theory

Prove that the sequence k,k,k,...,k of length k+1 is graphic, thereby proving that there exist k-regular graphs on k+1 vertices. Identify this class of graphs.
I can't seem to understand the question. Anyone have any suggestions how to prove it?

Comment: I don't understand exactly what does "that there exist k-regular...". That's obviously that I can build this graph.

Comment: So that's will be $K_{k}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the degree sequence of the complete graph $K_{k+1}$.

Comment: How do I prove it's graphic?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/595504)

Comment: @Jonas: Could you please elaborate why this doesn't answer the question? I know how the site works, I wasn't critiquing or requesting clarification, I thought and still think that this answers the question.

Comment: @nyorkr23: A graphic sequence is a sequence that is the degree sequence of some graph. Thus there's nothing left to prove -- exhibiting a graph that has this sequence as its degree sequence is the entire proof.

Comment: I think I understand what you're trying to say. The sequence is graphic because the sequence itself can create a complete graph on k+1 vertices. Is that correct?

Comment: @nyorkr23: I don't know what you mean by a sequence creating a graph. I get the impression that you should perhaps look up [the definition of a graphic sequence](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphicSequence.html).

Comment: Your answer is certainly correct, but the way the question is posed ("thereby proving"!) suggests that the asker had a different kind of solution in mind: probably showing that the sequence is graphic by using the Havel-Hakimi theorem (which is easy by induction).